# How to add a secondary Title to Plotly graph

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I have a number of plotly graphs and I want to add several components from the DataFrame to the plot title area. I have the bulk of the text in the title but what I would like to do is add more text where I have indicated in yellow in the picture below.
One way is to have a very long title with a lot of spaces in it, but is there a way to have two titles (or a title and something else that looks like a title) and be able to control the position of them? Something like two titles, one justified left, one justified right?  I've looked at 'labels' but they are inside the graph and I'm using the Subplot titles as shown.

```
figN.update_layout(template="plotly_dark",
title_text="Node Separations.   Line: "+str(name)+" Seq: "+str(Seq))
```

[image: Add secondary 'title' to yellow area]